# confused about accessing store information with express-session

Tags: node.js, storage, express-session

I am using Express/Node.js and the 'express-session' module.  I have setup a datastore using LokiStore to create a storage area for the session data:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var LokiStore = require('connect-loki')(session);

var options = {
 path: './session-store',
 autosave: true,
 ttl: 0
}; // options for LokiStore

var sess = {
 store: new LokiStore(options),
   // using LokiStore with express-session
   // as the store method, replacing the default memory store
 secret: 'somereallysecretkeyinsertedhere',
 cookie: {},
 resave: true,
 saveUninitialized: true,
 maxAge : Date().now + (60 * 1000 * 30),
 unset: 'destroy'
};
```

I am extremely confused on how I am to access certain bits of information stored in the storage file created by the LokiStore.  For example if I wish to fetch the length (# of sessions in the store) I am unable to do:

```
var store = sess.store;
console.log(store.length);  //'undefined'
```

Or get all sessions as an array:

```
store.all(function(error, sessions) {
console.log(sessions);
})
```

Or retrieve a certain sid:

```
store.get("u3TD6cgFwlFDiKQ65eKnT40OfAI2zeAQ", function(error, sessions) {
console.log(sessions);
})
```

I suppose I could write a 'readstream' routine using the "fs" module to parse the file generated as the store storage however that seems inefficient, to say the least.  Any help that improves my understanding of the operation of the express-session module specifically relating to the information store would be greatly appreciated...I thank you in advance...!

Comment: You can look at the session store interface that `require('connect-loki')(session)` offers here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#session-store-implementation in order to be compatible with express-session.  This is the interface that express-session uses.  You could perhaps use that interface also.  How the session data is stored inside the actual Loki database is up to the `connect-loki` module and you would have to look at that code to see how/where it is putting things inside the Loki database if you want to access the database directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes I was looking at the link you provided...that is where I got the 'store.all' and 'store.get' calls that should be usable.  Unfortunately the 'connect-loki' documentation is rather sparse on their NPM page.  Thanks for the heads up that the interface is dependent  on the store, rather than on 'express-session'...I thought any store listed in the 'Compatible Session Stores' section would be used in the same way.

Comment: Yeah, it's `connect-loki` that supplies the express-session interface and then decides how to store the data in the actual database.  If the connect-loki doc is insufficient, go look at the actual [connect-loki source code](https://github.com/Requarks/connect-loki#readme).  That's the beauty of open source, npm and github.

Comment: Thanks again...I will have a look.  That is a good idea.  You are a fountain of information!